# Laravel 4, Pass a variable to route in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

> How Can I pass the variable (stock.id) return from Ajax response to the route to generate the url to edit a stock

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'sectors/stocks/' + $(this).data('sector-id'),
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function() {
                $('.stocks_list').html('Loading...');
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $('.stocks_list').html('<ul>');
            $.each(data, function(index, obj_data) {
                $.each(obj_data.stocks, function(indx, stock) {
                    $('.stocks_list').append('<li><a href="{{route("admin.stocks.edit","'+stock.id+'")}}">' + stock.symbol + ' </a></li>');     
                });
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can first use a placeholder to generate the URL with and then replace that in javascript.

```
var url = '{{ route("admin.stocks.edit", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace(':id', stock.id);
$('.stocks_list').append('<li><a href="'+url+'">' + stock.symbol + ' </a></li>');
```

Comment: OK, It works now, Thanks, Actually I made a little change because Laravel escape the character %

Comment: Ooops you're right. What did you use instead of `%`?

Comment: I just changed it to another string like S_id_E

Answer (score 16):

In my opinion the simplest way is by concatenating javascript variable with blade string as follows.

**Case 1: Route paramter is required**

In this case pass the empty string in place of route parameter to by pass the required validation.

```
var url = "{{route('admin.stocks.edit', '')}}"+"/"+stock.id;
```

**Case 2: Route paramter is optional**

In this case you do not have to pass the empty string.

```
var url = "{{route('admin.stocks.edit')}}"+"/"+stock.id;
```

Answer (score 6):

**Best way to use route in ajax.**

---

Add route in **hidden input** or **take as a attribute** into the button or link. Like below.

This will save the other jquery code like get id and pass into the url. It's simple just get the url from input and pass as a URL. That's it.

```
<a data-url="{{ route('delete.PendingPatient',['id' => $u->id]) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete"> Delete </a>
```

---

**Route**

```
<?php

Route::delete('/pending_patient/{id}','PatientController@pending_patient'])->name('delete.PendingPatient');
```

---

**jQuery**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

          jQuery(document).on('click','.btn_delete',function(){
             var current = jQuery(this);
             var url = current.data('url');

             $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType:'json',
                    beforeSend:function() {
                        $('.stocks_list').html('Loading...');
                    }
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $('.stocks_list').html('<ul>');
                });

              });

         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks lukasgeiter, you make my day. It works. Only must to  change the replace method because laravel scape ":" to "%3A"

```
var url = '{{ url("/admin/solicitud", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace('%3Aid', data.datos[i].id);
dhtml+='<td><a href="'+url+'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Ver más...</a></td>';
```

or simple let the id string only

```
var url = '{{ url("/admin/solicitud", "id") }}';
url = url.replace('id', data.datos[i].id);
dhtml+='<td><a href="'+url+'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Ver más...</a></td>';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let calculatedId = e.currentTarget.id.split("_")[1];

let url = '{{route('queryToggleStatus', ':queryId')}}';

url = url.replace(':queryId', calculatedId);

$.get(url, function(data, status) {
  console.log (data);
})
```

Comment: Its the same as @lukasgeiter solution!

Answer (score -1):

if is required param:

```js
$("#program_id").change(function (e) {
    const $programId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: `{{route('get-group-subjects-by-program', '')}}/${$programId}`,
        context: document.body,
        type: "GET",
        .
        .
        .
    });
});
```

If not required param:

```
$("#program_id").change(function (e) {
    const $programId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: `{{route('get-group-subjects-by-program')}}/${$programId}`,
        .
        .
        .
    });
});
```