# Passing Javascript variable to route in laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.3

I'm having a Laravel blade form which includes a table wihch displays some data from the database. And when i click on a certain column i wrote a js function to catch that id of the certain selected item to a js variable "var selectedItem".

Now i wanna pass this js variable to the 'edit.item.blade' page and load the relevant record corresponding to this value.

My question is what is the best way to edit a selected item in laravel ? and is there anyway to pass this JS variable to a route at a button click event and load the 'edit.item.blade' using the relevant record to edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4, Pass a variable to route in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634285/laravel-4-pass-a-variable-to-route-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you usually do in laravel is pass the id of the record you want to see in the url. Say you want to view the details of a report with the id of 1 you'd go to the url "/reports/1" which points to a show function in the reports controller.

**Routes**

In your routes/web.php you'd add:

```
Route::get('/reports/{report}',RecordController@show);
```

What this is does is take anything typed after */reports/* and pass it to the show function. So if you'd go to */reports/1* the route would pass *1* to the show function

**Controller**

In your controller you have to make a show function which accepts the variable passed by your route. You'd then take that variable to look up the corresponding record and pass it along to a view.
Which would look like this

```
public function show($id){
    $report = Report::find($id); // Find the corresponding report

    // Pass the report along to the view resources/views/reports/show.blade.php
    return view('reports.show',compact($report));
}
```

**Show view**

In your show view you can now use `$report` to get any information from the report like `$report->name`, depending on your database.

**Index**

Now in the index view, the view you were talking about I presume, you loop over all records from some table. Since you haven't included any code in your post I'm just going to assume you loop over your data using a foreach loop. Using that loop we can give each record a link depending on their id.
Which would look a bit like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Name </td>
    <td> Edit </td>
  </tr>
  @foreach($reports as $report)
    <tr>
      <td> $report->name </td>
      <td><a href="{{ url('reports/' . $report->id) }}">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</table>
```