# Appending form which has delete action to a laravel blade file using javascript

Tags: jquery, json, laravel, routes, append

```
      $.get('/ajax-scheduleCourseS?cat_id=' + n+'&cat_id1='+cat_id1, function(data){
                $('#tab3').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, result) {
                    $('#tab3').append(
                        '<tr>'+
                        '<td class="tabco1" >'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '<td class="tabco2" >'+
                        result.code+'( '+result.type+' )'+
                        '{{ Form::open(['route'=>['admin.delete.anyschedule',result.id],'method'=>'DELETE']) }}'+
                        '<input type="image" src="{{URL::asset('trash.png')}}" alt="Submit" border="0" width="20px" height="20px">'+
                        '{{ Form::close() }}'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'
                    );
                });

            });
```

Here I am trying to append a row to table which has id=tab3.There the result is obtained through json.The returned object is the result(in the above code) variable.But the porblem here is that I cant insert the result.id(here it is identified as a text but not as a variable and returned objects have porperties like id,code,type) to 'route'=>['admin.delete.anyschedule',result.id] as result.id is not identified as a variable.I have tried it in various ways.Can anyone help?

Comment: when I used a numeric value such as 1,2,3(if data are present in the database) the route is working.So I guess there must be a way to pass a dynamic variable.Can anyone guide me in the correct direction??

Comment: Is there a reason you've wanted to concatenate the `Form` snippet in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27634351/3385827

Comment: sorry I didn`t get the idea??     
 
Is there a reason you've wanted to concatenate the Form snippet in the first place?

Comment: The `Form` blade template itself. You can append the form itself (e.g `'<form route="admin.delete.anyschedule' + result.id + '"></form>'`)

Comment: The Form blade template itself. You can append the form itself (e.g '<form route="admin.delete.anyschedule' + result.id + '"></form>') I have tried this.There is no error.When I clicked it refreshes but the item is not deleted

Comment: Thanks every one.Instead of route , action must be used within the form with the url specified in the web.php.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add blade expression in external javascript code. As javascript runs on client's browser and it does not have any access to server's variable. As blade expressions are executed only on server and not on client.

You can write the javascript code in php file or use form tag to get it work.

Comment: That means I have to use typical html coding like <form........></form> here.Is it?

Comment: External js files can not access blade template..u can write the javascript code in php file or use <form></form>. to get it work.

Comment: '<form route="admin.delete.anyschedule' + subcatObj.id + 'method="GET">'+
                            '<input type="image" src="{{URL::asset('trash.png')}}" alt="Submit" border="0" width="20px" height="20px">'+
                            '</form>'+ I have tried like this.When I clicked it refreshes but the item is not deleted.

Comment: I have even  tried changing the method to get,post and delete in such case same time by changing along it in web.php

Comment: route is not known by form..use action instead. {{URL::asset('trash.png')}} is also a blade expression

Comment: Finally it worked.Thanks dude.It was really a huge help.I was stuck here for a while.Thanks

Comment: '<form action="showScheduledel/' + result.id + 'method="GET">'+
                           
                            '</form>'+ It worked Cheers