# how to create ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

i want to show my data when i click button with ajax.

here ajax that i try.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#detailptr', function(){
       var idpartner = $(this).data("vid");
       $('#detailptr').html("Loading...").prop("disabled", true);
       $.ajax({
          url:"{{URL::route('front.partnereemployee')}}"+idpartner,
          method:"GET",
          data:{idpartner:idpartner},
          dataType:"text",
          success:function(data)
          {
             if(data != '')
             {
                //$('#remove_row').remove();
          $("#remove_row").html(data);
             }
             else
             {
                //$('#detailptr').html("Sudah Semuanya");
             }
          }
       });
    });
  });
```

my html

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{ $key }}" data-vid="{{ $companys->CompanyID }}" id="detailptr">{{ $companys->CompanyName }}</a>
```

and this is my route

```
Route::get('/partnere/{id}', 'Front\Home\FrontController@employeeajax')->name('front.partnereemployee');
```

when i try to run, it always show me

> Missing required parameters for [Route: front.partnereemployee] [URI:
>   partnere/{id}]

Comment: Change this `url:"{{URL::route('front.partnereemployee')}}"+idpartner,` to `url:"{{URL::route('front.partnereemployee', "idpartner")}}"`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27634351/9193055) should solve your problem. You have to pass a placeholder for the required route param and then later replace it your real param in javascript.

Comment: Try replacing ```url:"{{URL::route('front.partnereemployee')}}"+idpartner,``` with

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a shorthand for ajax calls which is more convenient
[$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
[$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

for your case it would be

```
$.get('{{ route('front.partnereemployee') }}' + idpartner, {idpartner: idpartner}).done(function () {
        alert("second success");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    }).always(function () {
        alert("finished");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ther simple way for make get request in laravel Ajax.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type:"GET",
    url : 'your-url',
    data: {key:data},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
                if (data.status = true) {
                document.getElementById("alert-message").innerHTML = data.message;

                console.log(data);
               } else {
                  alert('failed');
               }
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("ajax failed");
            })
})
```

and if you want to pass CSRF token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

add this line in your header so that you can pass token in Jquery using below code,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(e);
```