# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) using laravel 8 / ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to display an image in a HTML bloc , so I'm trying the following code.

So I'm using the following code :

My Route :

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','role:account_manager|admin|manager_de_filiale']], function() {  
Route::get('/getCasting/{id_casting}','App\Http\Controllers\ProjetController@getCasting');
});
```

My Controller :

```
public function getCasting()

    {
        $id_casting = request('id_casting');

        $castings = Casting::where('id_casting',$id_casting)->get();

       /* dd($states);*/
    
        $option = "<div class='d-flex flex-row mb-3 casting_details2'>
                                    <a class='d-block position-relative' href='#'>
                                        <img src='img/products/marble-cake-thumb.jpg' alt='Marble Cake'
                                        class='list-thumbnail border-0' />
                                        <span
                                        class='badge badge-pill badge-theme-2 position-absolute badge-top-right'>NEW</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>";


        foreach($castings as $casting){
            $option.= '<div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 casting_details2">
                                    <a class="d-block position-relative" href="#">
                                        <img src="/castingimages/'.$casting->photo.'" alt="Marble Cake"
                                        class="list-thumbnail border-0" />
                                        <span
                                        class="badge badge-pill badge-theme-2 position-absolute badge-top-right">NEW</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>';
        }
        return $option;
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {
    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
    var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
    //added data-index and outer..class
    $(".form_field_outer").append(`<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}"><div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-4"> <label for="inputState">Casting</label><select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting">
<option selected>Choose...</option><option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option> </select></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label><select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat"> <option selected>Choose...</option><option>...</option> </select></div><div class="card-body "><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button></div>
</div></div></div> `);
    $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field", function() {
    var index = $(this).closest(".outer").data('index') //get index
    $(".casting_details [data-index= " + index + "]").remove() //remove genrated casting_details2 as well
    $(this).closest(".outer").remove()
  })
  $("body").on("change", "select[name=id_casting]", function() {
    var index = $(this).closest(".outer").data('index') //get outer div index..

    //check if the data-id not there
    if ($(".casting_details [data-index= " + index + "]").length == 0) {
      //append new...
      $(".casting_details").append(`<div data-index= "${index}" class="card-body casting_details2"> <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 "> <a class="d-block position-relative" href="#"><img src="img/products/marble-cake-thumb.jpg" alt="Marble Cake"class="list-thumbnail border-0" /> <span  class="badge badge-pill badge-theme-2 position-absolute badge-top-right">NEW</span></a></div></div> `);
    }
    let id_casting = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
     $.get('/getCasting/' + id_casting, function(data) {
    //add content inside that
    $(".casting_details [data-index= " + index + "]").html("<img src=...../>"); //data

    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer">
    <!--added outer and data-index-->
    <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="0">
      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
            <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
            <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option>...</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Add</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>
<div>
  <div class="card mb-4 casting_details ">
<!-- will come here-->
  </div>
```

When I execute my code I get the following error :

```
The requested resource /castingimages/%22 was not found on this server.
```

And I get in my view :

[image]

I don't know where id the problem in my code , if you have any idea I will e grathfull

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where's the route definition to match the given route? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: the route definition is in my script

Comment: No, it's not. The route definition in your code only covers `/getCasting/{id_casting}`, and it's pretty obvious that this does not match `castingimages/%22`

Comment: that is the problem , it should be for example getCasting/18

Comment: Then you need to adjust the code that issues that request - well, depending on which problem you try to solve? The error message is given as you are calling such a URL in the `img` tag, but you are not using that on the AJAX request

Comment: Missing a space in `alt="Marble Cake"class="...`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the part where you added the `id_casting` to the URL.

I refactored to a named route.

```
Route::get('/getCasting/{id_casting}','App\Http\Controllers\ProjetController@getCasting')->name('getCasting');
```

Try using this for the AJAX request.

```
let id_casting = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
let url = '{{ route("getCasting", ":id_casting") }}';
url = url.replace(':id_casting', id_casting);

$.get(url, function (data) {
    //add content inside that
    $(".casting_details [data-index=" + index + "]").html("<img src=...../>"); //data
});
```

Reference [Similar Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634285/laravel-4-pass-a-variable-to-route-in-javascript)

Comment: @lourdkenny , thank you for your help, I did that , but I get always this error : `The requested resource /castingimages/%22 was not found on this server.`

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't call the url  `{{ route("getCasting", ":id_casting") }}` , it calls the url of the image