# How do I add unknown parameters at route definition time laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I will explain as much as possible

```php
// route
category/{id} // ->name('category.action')

//form
<form action="route('category.action')">

<!-- some input's --!>

</form>
```

I have some buttons have a function and I have one form if a specific button is pressed the button id will be switched to route by javascript

Is there a way to make the paramter id flexible change with pressing the button

Comment: https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Comment: Prevent submit the form and then submit it by building in the form url in Javascript.

Comment: Put a dummy string as your parameter, and replace it with JS. Here's an example (the question is a bit confusing, and it applies to any Laravel not just L4, but the accepted answer is the solution):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634285/laravel-4-pass-a-variable-to-route-in-javascript/63860577

Comment: @Don'tPanic This is it