# Pass variable to a Laravel route inside an href

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, openlayers

So i'm using Laravel 8 to create a project, there's a map that i created using OpenLayers and that map has "points" (or features) in it, each point has a name already stablished, and each time i click in one of the points a pop up appears with the name of the point and a link that it's supposed to take me to another page where more information is going to be displayed, the part of the code that's giving me problems is this:

```
if(feature){
        var text = feature.get('name');
        content.innerHTML = text + ' ' + '<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('local',['nombre' =>  text]) }}">{{ __('Ver menú') }}></a>';
}else{
        content.innerHTML = '';
     }
```

it throws me this error:

> Use of undefined constant text - assumed 'text' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

So i'm assuming i can't pass the variable just like that, but i don't know how i could do it,this is the route i defined:

```
Route::get('/local/{nombre}', 'LocalController@index')->name('local');
```

And this is the code of the controller;

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class LocalController extends Controller
    {
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index($nombre)
{
    return view('local', ['nombre' => $nombre]);
}
```

}

Thank you in advance for any recommendation/tip/information (also, sorry if the code looks a little messy here, i'm new here and don't know how to give it a proper styling hehehe)

Comment: I think you need to wrap the text in quotation in your first block code, right here route('local',['nombre' =>  text]). the text is being considered as variable by Php

Comment: i did try doing that and it did solve the error, but it takes me to "local/text" instead of, for example, "local/pointName".

Comment: [You should try this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27634351/3787519)

Comment: @InsaneSkull this solved the problem, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with **text** in this part

```
{{ route('local',['nombre' =>  text]) }}
```

it should be like this

```
{{ route('local',['nombre' =>  'text']) }}
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: i did try doing that and it did solve the error, but it takes me to "local/text" instead of, for example, "local/pointName".

Comment: you should pass the value you want from the controller or put it directly if you want by replacing "text"